# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsynctex_parser: No such file or directory

Tags: rust

I want to invoke the C function from rust, first I compiled the c so file named `synctex_parser.so` and put it in the src solder `src/so/synctex_parser.so`, then define the `synctex.rs` like this:

```
use std::os::raw::{c_int, c_char};

#[link(name = "synctex_parser")]
extern "C" {
    pub fn synctex_scanner_new_with_output_file(output: c_char, build_directory: c_char, parse: c_int);
}
```

when I compile the project using command like this in project root diectory:

```
RUSTFLAGS='-L./src/so' cargo build
```

shows error:

```
    -aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/aarch64-apple-darwin/lib" "-o" "/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/texhub-server/target/debug/deps/texhub_server-2001a40521c553e6" "-Wl,-dead_strip" "-nodefaultlibs" "-L./src/so/"
  = note: ld: library not found for -lsynctex_parser
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
          

error: could not compile `texhub-server` due to previous error
```

I also tried this:

```
RUSTFLAGS='-C link-args=-L./src/so/' cargo build
```

this command seems did not work:

```
cargo rustc -- -C link-args='-Wl,-rpath,/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/backend/texhub-server/src/so/'
```

Comment: While the dupe does static linking, the error is the same, you're missing the `lib` prefix on your `synctex_parser.so`. It should be renamed to `libsynctex_parser.so`.

Comment: How about building and linking the `.so` file as one step before running cargo build? https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-script-examples.html#building-a-native-library. There is a Rusty way for probing `so` files also: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-script-examples.html#linking-to-system-libraries

Comment: it seems an another good way to sovle the c invoke. @Raeisi